# How to click() an element with jsaction preventdefault script using puppeteer or javascript?

Tags: javascript, selenium, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer to click on this element

```
<span jsslot="" class="z80M1 G3hhxb" jsaction="click:o6ZaF(preventDefault=true); mousedown:lAhnzb; mouseup:Osgxgf; mouseenter:SKyDAe; mouseleave:xq3APb;touchstart:jJiBRc; touchmove:kZeBdd; touchend:VfAz8(preventMouseEvents=true)" jsname="j7LFlb" aria-label="For myself" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"><div class="aBBjbd MbhUzd" jsname="ksKsZd"></div><div class="uyYuVb oJeWuf" jsname="RZzeR"><div class="jO7h3c">For myself</div></div></span>
```

I have tried javascript `click()` and `dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousedown'))/'mouseup'`.

I have also tried puppeteers `tap()` and `click()`.

Nothing works.

Observation: This element registers a click event when I try to do a manual right-click.

I just need to click on this element to take me to next page.

Comment: check if its under iframe

Comment: No, I checked again.